# RecyclerView Clipping Into ScrollView with CornerRadius

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a recycler view inside a linear layout and the linear layout's parent is a scrollview whose background has a corner radius. When you scroll the view the recycler view appears on top of the corners of the scrollview clipping into the view.[This is the view without scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWl9f.png)

[Here's the view when you scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aljRw.png)

Comment: Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Also can you please attach the images to the post. We do not encourage remote links because the question will make no sense when the links stop working. Thank you for your understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two soutions:

1. You should add [more horizontal padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJw86.png) for your RecyclerView to avoid sharp corners:
2. You should add fake/artificial inverted blue round [corners](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0iuq.png)
3. Just add padding from top but it is [dirty solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xq6Ct.png)

Comment: Thanks this worked for me I added more horizontal padding to fix it.

Comment: Can you provide more details on how to add an inverted rounded corners